# Grails 3.2.0 deployed on Tomcat getting 404

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails3

Hey just upgraded to Grails 3.2.0 (from 3.2.0.RC2) and tried deploying to Tomcat 7.0.64 and Tomcat 8.5.5 running Java 8.0_101.  I now just get a 404 error from Tomcat but doing a run-app all is good.  Tomcat deploys without error and I can see the application in the Tomcat Manager and all looks good.  This was working when I was using 3.2.0.M2 but since then I upgraded to 3.2.0.RC1 and RC2 and then to 3.2.0. The startup of the war seems to go well (without any major errors) and I went into Tomcat manager and can see the war started and is running.  Any ideas want went wrong?

Comment: "Any ideas how to debug?" - It would depend on what is leading to the 404.  If a particular subset of requests is 404ing that might suggest a different approach than if every request to the app is 404ing.

Comment: @Joe your tomcat not able pickup war.Please check it into catilina of tomcat file.Or Try  restart your tomcat.

Comment: Think I figured it out.  Caused by adding a new dependency in the 3.2.0.  I added an issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10196 to the Grails Issues.

Comment: I will provide my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the process of upgrading from 3.2.0.RC2 to 3.2.0 I added a new dependency:

```
provided "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant"
```

Based on what a new 3.2.0 create-app generated by default.  Just remove this dependency and the application returned to running on Tomcat.

Create an issue on the Grails list.

[Grails Issue](http://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10196)